# Calculate row means based on (partial) matching column names

Tags: r

I am starting with 3 large data tables (named A1,A2,A3). Each table has 4 data columns (V1-V4), 1 "Date" column that is constant across all three tables, and thousands of rows.

Here is some dummy data that approximates my tables.

```
A1.V1<-c(1,2,3,4)
A1.V2<-c(2,4,6,8)
A1.V3<-c(1,3,5,7)
A1.V4<-c(1,2,3,4)


A2.V1<-c(1,2,3,4)
A2.V2<-c(2,4,6,8)
A2.V3<-c(1,3,5,7)
A2.V4<-c(1,2,3,4)


A3.V1<-c(1,2,3,4)
A3.V2<-c(2,4,6,8)
A3.V3<-c(1,3,5,7)
A3.V4<-c(1,2,3,4)

Date<-c(2001,2002,2003,2004)

DF<-data.frame(Date, A1.V1,A1.V2,A1.V3,A1.V4,A2.V1,A2.V2,A2.V3,A2.V4,A3.V1,A3.V2,A3.V3,A3.V4)
```

So this is what my data frame ends up looking like:

```
  Date A1.V1 A1.V2 A1.V3 A1.V4 A2.V1 A2.V2 A2.V3 A2.V4 A3.V1 A3.V2 A3.V3 A3.V4
1 2001     1     2     1     1     1     2     1     1     1     2     1     1
2 2002     2     4     3     2     2     4     3     2     2     4     3     2
3 2003     3     6     5     3     3     6     5     3     3     6     5     3
4 2004     4     8     7     4     4     8     7     4     4     8     7     4
```

My goal is to calculate the row mean for each of the matching columns from each data table. So in this instance, I would want row means for all columns ending in V1, all columns ending in V2, all columns ending in V3 and all columns ending in V4.

The end result would look like this

```
      V1  V2  V3  V4
2001   1   2   1   1
2002   2   4   3   2
2003   3   6   5   3
2004   4   8   7   4
```

So my question is, how to I go about calculating row means based on a partial match in the column name?

Thanks

Comment: Can we assume that we cannot rely on the positional ordering of the columns? i.e. the "matching" columns may be irregularly spaced?

Comment: No, we can not rely on the positional ordering. And the actual data set I am working with has many more columns, so specifying column positioning would be a hassle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure it can be done more elegantly, but this is one possibility that seems to work.

```
# declare the column names
colnames = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4")

# calculate the means
means = lapply(colnames, function(name) { apply(DF[,grep(name, names(DF))], 1, mean) })

# build the result
result = do.call(cbind, means)
result = as.data.frame(t(result))
rownames(result) = DF$Date
```

I should also describe, what I did.

First, I declared the column names to be partially matched.

Then, using the `grep` command to partially select the columns in your data frame (that matched the particular substring). The `apply` command calculates the means and `lapply` does it for all columns partially matched by the substring.

Using `do.call` and `cbind` (as suggested by DWin), we concatenate individual columns.
Finally, we set the column names from the `Date` column of the original data frame.

The problem can be solved more elgantly and efficiently, see solutions by DWin and Maiasaura.

Comment: That is rather a tortuous path to completion, especially the for-loop that could be replaced by just : `do.call(cbind, means)`

Comment: Reasonable suggestion, updated the post accordingly. I have used R seldom for some time now, but I still do things the hard way :). Love the solution by you and @Maiasaura, by the way.

Answer (score 7):

```
colnames = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4")
res <- sapply(colnames, function(x) rowMeans(DF [, grep(x, names(DF))] )  )
rownames(res) <- DF$Date
res
     V1 V2 V3 V4
2001  1  2  1  1
2002  2  4  3  2
2003  3  6  5  3
2004  4  8  7  4
```

The R `grep` function returns an integer vector that is used to selectively "pull" columns containing individual "V"-column names from the larger dataframe.

If you needed to generate the names automagically:

```
> unique(sapply(strsplit(names(DF)[-1], ".", fixed=TRUE), "[", 2) )
[1] "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4"
```

Comment: `res` is not assigned with any value

Comment: Good catch. I think I was running it without assignment until I got the right expected result but then forgot to put the assignment in. Fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

```
library(plyr)
ddply(DF, .(Date), function(x) {
    foo <- melt(x, id.vars = 1)
    foo$variable <- substr(foo$variable, 4, 6)
    return(dcast(foo, Date ~ variable, mean))
    })
Date V1 V2 V3 V4
1 2001  1  2  1  1
2 2002  2  4  3  2
3 2003  3  6  5  3
4 2004  4  8  7  4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep` with `value = T` to get the appropriate names and then create  call to `eval` within the `j` component of a `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
# convert to a data.table
DT <- data.table(DF)
 # the indices we wish to group
.index <- paste0('V',1:3)
# a list containing the names
name_list <- mapply(grep, pattern = as.list(.index ), 
                  MoreArgs = list(x= names(DT),value=T ), SIMPLIFY=F)
 # create the expression
.e <- parse(text=sprintf('list( %s)', paste(mapply(sprintf, .index, lapply(name_list, paste, collapse = ', '), 
            MoreArgs = list(fmt = '%s = mean(c(%s), na.rm = T)')), collapse = ',')))

DT[, eval(.e),by=Date]

##    Date V1 V2 V3
## 1: 2001  1  2  1
## 2: 2002  2  4  3
## 3: 2003  3  6  5
## 4: 2004  4  8  7

# what .e looks like
.e 
## expression(list( V1 = mean(c(A1.V1, A2.V1, A3.V1), na.rm = T),V2 = mean(c(A1.V2, A2.V2, A3.V2), na.rm = T),V3 = mean(c(A1.V3, A2.V3, A3.V3), na.rm = T)))
```

Comment: This torture seems to be induced by @Vinterwoo conflating two categorical types into one column names vector.  In `data.table` we'd keep it in long format and then simply do: `DT[,mean(var),by="A,V"]`.  Some of these questions I'd be tempted to answer "Why?"   DWin's approach but on a data.table with `with=FALSE` is probably simpler.