# How to grep columns matching a pattern and calculate the row means of those columns and add the mean values as a new column to the data frame in r?

Tags: r, regex

I would like to grep name of columns and calculate their row mean and add the mean value as a new column to data frame. 
Here is my data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(smp1.ex.rep1 = c(1,2,4,2), smp1.ex.rep2 = c(2,4,5,2), smp1.ex.rep3 = c(3,2,3,3), smp2.int.rep1 = c(3,2,4,5), smp2.int.rep2 = c(5,4,3,4), smp3.ex.rep1 = c(2,3,4,2), smp3.int.rep2 = c(1,3,5,6), smp3.int.rep3 = c(3,6,2,6))
```

my df looks as follows:

```
> df
 smp1.ex.rep1  smp1.ex.rep2  smp1.ex.rep3  smp2.int.rep1  smp2.int.rep2
    1             2              3               3               5
    2             4              2               2               4
    4             5              3               4               3
    2             2              3               5               4
```

I want to grep the columns that have the same pattern till "rep*" and calculate their rowmean and mutate it as a new column.

For example take columns smp1.ex with rep1, rep2, rep3 together and take columns smp2.int with rep1, rep2 at the end together. and have the row means of each set of columns with the name smp1,ex.mean and smp2.int.mean added to data frame.

the desired output would be:

```
  smp1.ex.rep1 smp1.ex.rep2 smp1.ex.rep3 smp2.int.rep1 smp2.int.rep2 smp1.ex.mean smp2.int.mean
   1            2            3             3              5              2.00          4.0
   2            4            2             2              4              2.66          3.0
   4            5            3             4              3              4.00          3.5
   2            2            3             5              4              2.33          4.5
```

here is what I am trying to do:

```
names <- colnames(df)

names <- unique(gsub("rep*.*", "", names))
df <- rowMeans(df[,grep(paste(names[1:length(names)], 1:3, sep = "."), colnames(df))])
```

Do you have any ideas how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: Calculating row mean based on column name partial match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40246107/r-calculating-row-mean-based-on-column-name-partial-match)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option is to remove the digits at the end (`\\d+$`) with `sub`, use that to `split` the dataset into a `list` of `data.frame`s, get the `rowMeans` and assign it to new columns in the dataset

```
nm1 <- sub("\\d+$", "", names(df))
df[paste0(unique(nm1), "_mean")] <- sapply(split.default(df, nm1), rowMeans)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `cbind` to add the additional columns and `grepl` (or `grep`) to select them for passage to `rowMeans`:

```
 df.new <- cbind( df, smp1.ex.mean = rowMeans( df[ , grepl("ex", names(df)] ),
                      smp2.int.mean = rowMeans( df[ , grepl("int", names(df)] )  )
```