# Taking means of data frame columns based on column name

Tags: r, bigdata

Disclaimer: I am an R and big-data newbie; I'm fairly decent with Python, but I have little experience with manipulating large data and don't know the common R methods for doing what I imagine should be fairly common tasks.

I have a bunch of data (in a data frame) from an experiment where each sample was run in duplicate. The headers look something like this:

```
> foo.sampledata[1:3,1:5]
         uniq.id jb_229.002_2 jb_229.002_1 jb_229.006_2 jb_229.006_1
1 400.2787_44.47            0            0            0         5629
2 406.2713_72.81            0         7451        16315            0
3 406.5656_41.37            0            0            0            0
```

There are 40 columns of sample data and about 26,000 rows for each column.

What I want to do is to take the mean of each sample's two runs (e.g. `jb_229.002_2` and `jb_229.002_1`, above) for every row in each pair of columns, and then store that under a new column named e.g. `jb_229.002`.

The solution I was using on my (smaller) test data set came from another stackoverflow question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12397402):

```
foo.means <- ddply(foo.sampledata, .(uniq.id), function(x) {
    foo <- melt(x, id.vars = 1)
    foo$variable <- substr(foo$variable, 1, 10)
    return(dcast(foo, uniq.id ~ variable, mean))})
```

This works well with my smaller test set but takes up all my RAM and essentially crashes R when I try to do it with the full set. I understand why it's taking so long – it's creating huge new tables twice – but I don't know another way to do it.

Any advice/resources/examples/public shaming appreciated!

Comment: Re your comment to Allen, you can find examples for data.table by reading through the vignettes: http://r-datatable.com/Getting-started I'd suggest going through them in order.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I'll check it out.

Comment: Also some inside as to how you came to appreciate public shaming will certainly be helpful :)

Comment: Heh well, I've been at this long enough to know that if you ask questions without first R-ing  TFM in its entirety you probably deserve a little ;)

Comment: Aaaand you have a lot more respect now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answers everyone – they are both succinct and well designed. I went through the `data.table` vignettes and wound up doing this with that datatype as follows:

```
# Truncate names so jb_229-002_2 and jb_229-002_1 are both jb_229-001
setnames(foo,substring(names(foo),1,10))

# Stack every other column
foo.c = rbind(foo[,c(1,seq(2,ncol(foo),by=2)),with=FALSE],
              foo[,c(1,seq(3,ncol(foo),by=2)),with=FALSE])

# for each uid, calculate the mean of each column of the subset.
foo.means = foo.c[ , lapply(.SD, mean), by=uniq.id ]
```

The other answers actually do a better job of addressing my question with regard to programmatically matching the names of the columns – I kind of kludge here by just alternating columns in my `rbind`. Do me a favor and don't tell anyone.

Thanks again all!

Answer (score 2):

If your example is representative, you can do this and it should be very fast for such a small number of columns:

```
DF <- read.table(text = "         uniq.id jb_229.002_2 jb_229.002_1 jb_229.006_2 jb_229.006_1
                 1 400.2787_44.47            0            0            0         5629
                 2 406.2713_72.81            0         7451        16315            0
                 3 406.5656_41.37            0            0            0            0")

#make sure duplicates are in right order
DF <- DF[, c(1, order(names(DF)[-1])+ 1)]

#loop over column pairs
res <- cbind(DF[, 1, drop = FALSE],
             sapply(seq_len((ncol(DF) - 1) %/% 2), function(i, DF) {
               n1 <- substring(names(DF)[2 * i], 1, nchar(names(DF)[2 * i]) - 2)
               n2 <- substring(names(DF)[2 * i - 1], 1, nchar(names(DF)[2 * i]) - 2)
               stopifnot(n1 == n2)
               setNames(data.frame((DF[, 2 * i] + DF[, 2 * i - 1]) / 2),
                        n1)
             }, DF = DF[, -1]))
#         uniq.id jb_229.002 jb_229.006
#1 400.2787_44.47        0.0     2814.5
#2 406.2713_72.81     3725.5     8157.5
#3 406.5656_41.37        0.0        0.0
```

Note that `(DF[,1] + DF[,2]) / 2` is usually faster than `rowMeans(DF[, 1:2])`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial answer, that I think could be helpful in base R.

```
# get unique names of trial variables
myCols <- unique(substr(names(df[-1]), 1, nchar(names(df[-1]))-2))
# construct a data.frame that combines the trials into a single column
setNames(data.frame(df[1],
                   lapply(myCols, function(i) rowSums(df[, grep(i, names(df))]))),
         c(names(df)[1], myCols))
```

which returns

```
         uniq.id jb_229.002 jb_229.006
1 400.2787_44.47          0       5629
2 406.2713_72.81       7451      16315
3 406.5656_41.37          0          0
```

Now, it might be easier to calculate the means.

---

If the goal is to calculate the means across pairs for each row, then you could use rowMeans as @roland points out in the comments, like this:

```
setNames(data.frame(df[1],
                   lapply(myCols,
                          function(i) rowMeans(df[, grep(i, names(df))]))),
         c(names(df)[1], myCols))
```

which returns

```
         uniq.id jb_229.002 jb_229.006
1 400.2787_44.47        0.0     2814.5
2 406.2713_72.81     3725.5     8157.5
3 406.5656_41.37        0.0        0.0
```