# Calculate column means based on (partial) matching row names

Tags: r

I am sure this is a very easy problem but I cannot figure it out. I have a data set with partially matching row names such as AA.11 AB. 11 AC.11 AA.12 AB.12 AC.12 etc. I would like to be able to easily calculate and plot the column means for different subsets such as all containing 'AA' in or '.12' in the name.

```
X<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
Y<-c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18)
Z<-c(1,3,5,7,10,13,16,19,22)

Name<-c("AA.11", "AA.12", "AA.13", "AB.11", "AB.12", "AB.13", "AC.11", 
"AC.12", "AC.13")

DF<-data.frame(Name,X,Y,Z)
```

I followed the solutions proposed in this thread: [Calculate row means based on (partial) matching column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397210/calculate-row-means-based-on-partial-matching-column-names)

```
rownames = c("AA", "AB", "AC", ".11", ".12", ".13")
sapply(rownames, function(x) colMeans(DF [grep(x, names(DF)), ]))
```

but then end up with an empty matrix. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: For the data you posted something like `sapply(rownames, function(x) colMeans(DF[grep(x, DF$Name), -1]))` works.

Comment: Awesome thank you that works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach using `tidyverse`

```
X<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
Y<-c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18)
Z<-c(1,3,5,7,10,13,16,19,22)

Name<-c("AA.11", "AA.12", "AA.13", "AB.11", "AB.12", "AB.13", "AC.11", "AC.12", "AC.13")

DF<-data.frame(Name,X,Y,Z)

library(tidyverse)

df_res = tibble(rownames = c("AA", "AB", "AC", ".11", ".12", ".13")) %>%  # save rownames of interest as a tibble
  mutate(d = map(rownames, ~DF[grep(.x, DF$Name),]),                      # get the corresponding subsets
         c_means = map(d, ~colMeans(.x[-1]))) %>%                         # get the corresponding column means
  print()                                                                 # print result

# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#     rownames d                    c_means  
#     <chr>    <list>               <list>   
#   1 AA       <data.frame [3 x 4]> <dbl [3]>
#   2 AB       <data.frame [3 x 4]> <dbl [3]>
#   3 AC       <data.frame [3 x 4]> <dbl [3]>
#   4 .11      <data.frame [3 x 4]> <dbl [3]>
#   5 .12      <data.frame [3 x 4]> <dbl [3]>
#   6 .13      <data.frame [3 x 4]> <dbl [3]>
```

So far you have an output that has stored the subsets (`d`) the process used to get the column means and the column means themselves (`c_means`), for each `rowname` you provided.

You can access those stored variables like this:

```
# see the subset used for AC
df_res$d[df_res$rownames == "AC"]

# [[1]]
#   Name X  Y  Z
# 7 AC.11 7 14 16
# 8 AC.12 8 16 19
# 9 AC.13 9 18 22


# see the column means for AC
df_res$c_means[df_res$rownames == "AC"]

# [[1]]
# X  Y  Z 
# 8 16 19 


# see all column means
df_res$c_means

# [[1]]
# X Y Z 
# 2 4 3 
# 
# [[2]]
# X  Y  Z 
# 5 10 10 
# 
# [[3]]
# X  Y  Z 
# 8 16 19 
# 
# [[4]]
# X Y Z 
# 4 8 8 
# 
# [[5]]
# X        Y        Z 
# 5.00000 10.00000 10.66667 
# 
# [[6]]
# X        Y        Z 
# 6.00000 12.00000 13.33333
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `DF$Name` in the `grep` function rather than `names(DF)`

Such that the code should look

```
rownames = c("AA", "AB", "AC", ".11", ".12", ".13") 
sapply(rownames, function(x) colMeans(DF [grep(x, DF$Name), ]))
```

since you are looking for means base of the value in the Name column rather than the column names.